# Change target of shebang

Tags: environment-variables, rhel-6, python3

I would like to create the target `python3` to be used in shebangs. Eg. use the first line `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.

What I tried:

- setenv python3 PATH_TO_BINARY, also put it into `.cshrc`, echo $python3 shows also path
- /bin/env NAME=python3 PATH_TO_BINARY, opens python3 but doesn't allow usage of the shebang. The same for /bin/env python3=PATH_TO_BINARY

In case it matters, I would like to solve the following problem:

I'm working on a `rhel 6` system were I cannot directly install `python3` however I can used it over `anaconda3` which is installed at an accessible network resource. Instead of putting the shebang with the absolute path I would like to properly set the python3 path write portable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it's not the `#!`-line you should be changing, but your `$PATH`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

This has the effect that the `python3` interpreter will be searched for in the directories listed in your `$PATH` variable.

If `python3` is installed in, e.g., `$HOME/local/bin`, then this directory must be present in `$PATH` *before* any other directory that may also contain a `python3` interpreter, otherwise that one will be used instead of your own in `$HOME/local/bin`.

So you need to set

```
PATH="$HOME/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Either on the command line, or in a shell initialization script (`~/.bashrc` for example). C-shell users do it differently...

```
set path = ($HOME/local/bin $path)
```

In general, the `#!`-line identifies *the interpreter* for the script, i.e. what program to use to parse and run the file. A `sed` script, for example, may use `#!/usr/bin/sed -f`.

Comment: That was it. Thanks for answering my question even though I actually asked the wrong one.